# Как обратиться к селектору тега script?

Tags: javascript, html

Как обратиться к `id="guessme-surprise_popup"` ?

```html
<script id="guessme-surprise_popup" type="text/template">
  <div class="ta-c">
    <div class="guessme-thermometer_ttip_superprize" style="width: auto">
      <div class="guessme-thermometer_ttip_img"></div>
      <span style="font-size: 15px; color: #621a3d;"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="ta-c">
    <div class="guessme-btn _blue _middle" onclick="guessme.manager.surprise.getHim();"><span>Забрать подарок</span></div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: точно так же, как если бы это был тег DIV

Comment: Если вы используете HTML внутри SCRIPT, вам нужно преобразовывать символы `<`, `>`, `&`, `"`, `'` в сущности. Подумайте внимательно зачем это необходимо! https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Entity

Answer (score 2):

Только начала изучать js. Если не ошибаюсь, то обращение

```
const popup = document.querySelector("#guessme-surprise_popup");
```

Но почему HTML, вписан в скрипт js?

Comment: Потому, что тег `script` - это необязательно JS. А сам код, который вы привели - верный.